# Text field validation. Validate first characters. iOS

Tags: ios

I'm validating a text field but I need first 4 characters only. How can I get only those characters and not a full text.  Thanks

Comment: Not specific to your substring needs, but an example of how to use Key Value Coding validation with a UITextField: https://github.com/quellish/KVCValidationExample

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSString *trimmedString = [textfield.text substringToIndex:4];
```

and pass `trimmedString` to validator method

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
NSString *textType = yourTextField.text;
NSString *character = [textAll substringToIndex:4];
```